# Combinatorics - create different words using all chars

Tags: combinatorics

I need help with this question:

a) How many different "words" could be created using all the characters of ABRACADABRA?

b) In how many of these there are no 2 A`s one next to the other?

c) In how many of the "words" in a) there are no 2 identical characters one next to the other?

**My attempt**:

a) is simple, its just $\frac{  11!  }{  (2!)\cdot (2!)\cdot (5!)}$.

Can I get help on b) and c)? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, machine brute-force? [ 11! ] \ [ (2!)(2!)(5!) ] is not so big set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b, look at a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) argument.  You have five As which require four slots between them.  You have two more slots to put in the line.  For c I think you have to do casework on b.  Look at how many ends got the two extra slots.  If the extra slots went one on each end, there is no threat from a doubling of another letter.  If there is only one end covered, you have one pair of slots that might have a double letter.  If neither end is covered, you might have two pair of slots or you might have a block of three.  See how many combinations from b get ruled out.

Comment: Thanks! but what I get in b) is 6! / 2!2!, for some reason the answer is multiplied by (7 choose 5). Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Your $\frac {6!}{2!2!}$ is placing the non-As in the slots.  The $7 \choose 5$ is from placing the two extra slots in the row from the stars and bars.

Answer (score 0):

I see that Ross Millikan has already answered but my explanation is a bit more verbose so posting here anyway for posterity. Unfortunately I don't have an answer to c).

#### a) How many different “words” could be created using all the characters of ABRACADABRA?

The total number of characters is 11, so the number of all possible permutations is: \[11! = 39916800\]

There are however some repeated characters: 5 A’s, 2 B’s and 2 R’s, so to get the number of distinct words we need to divide the number of all permutations by the product of number of permutations for each repeated character:

\[\frac{11!}{5!\times2!\times2!}=83160\]

---

#### b) In how many of these there are no 2 A`s one next to the other?

We can use the stars-and-bars method here. There are 5 ‘A’ characters and 6 other characters, therefore there are 7 positions between bars (which represent remaining characters) for A to be placed, so the number of different placements of A's is: \[{7 \choose 5}=21\]

Here’s one of those possibilities shown as a visual aid to understanding:

A | | A | A | A | | A

In each of those 21 positions, similarly to the calculation done in a), the remaining 6 characters (which are ‘B’ ,‘B’, ‘C’, ‘D’, ‘R, ’R’) can be permuted in \[\frac{6!}{2!\times2!}=180\] ways.

So the total number of words with no 2 A’s next to one another is \[21\times180=3780\] (out of the total of 83160, which means a random word has \[\frac{3780}{83160} = 0.0454545\] chance of having no consecutive ’A’s)

---